# Statistics usage of a database

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Is there a way to monitor statistics on usage of documents within a database?

I have a lotus notes database hosted on a local server. I know I can get some info from 'User Detail...' in Info tab of Database property (right click on the database from domino designer), which basically shows me which user accessed database and which CRUD action was performed, but I was looking for something more in depth i.e. which document in particular is read the most and by who.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this is StackOverflow, not SuperUser or ServerFault, I'm going to treat this as a programming question.  (On those other sites, they would tell you that tracking actions at the document level is not built into Notes and Domino's functionality, but there are some 3rd party add-on products that can do it for you.)

You can implement tracking features down to the document level in Notes and Domino using the Extension Manager API portion of the Notes C API. There is also a free package on the OpenNTF.org web site, called TriggerHappy, which provides a framework for using the Extension Manager features to call Java agents when events that you want to track occur.  This can make it significantly easier to accomplish what you want, but it will not scale as well for large user bases.

You should also bear in mind that since Notes and Domino are designed for use in a distributed environment in which users can do their work in local replica databases, a tracking mechanism that is based on an Extension Manager plugin running on the server may not see changes at the moment that users make them. Instead, it might see them when those changes replicate from the user's computer to the server -- and replication does not guarantee that order is preserved, so the server might see some things happen in a different order than what the user actually did.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the activity trends, see notes help.
If you need more details, you have to implement it by yourself.